# How to create a list of sites under a site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am totally new to sharepoint and just trying to get something up and running as a quick fix.

I have a Sharepoint portal from http://hostway.com at portal..com

**Example of what I need**

Say I have a site called `Colors`
and I have 3 different sites under `Colors` called `Red Blue Green`

On the main page of `Colors` site I would like to show a list of all the sites that exist under it, in this case `Red Blue Green`. I would also like to show a Description field corresponding to each site.

It should look like:

```
Site Name     | Description
--------------| -------------------
Red           | This is red
Blue          | This is blue
Green         | This is Green
```

When I try to add something to the main page by clicking `Site Actions -> Edit Page` all I see is `Add a Web Part`. When I click that and further click 'Advanced Web Part gallery and options' I see the following that I can add but none of them would achieve what I want.

```
Announcements
Calendar
Content Editor Web...
Form Web Part
Image Web Part
Links
Page viewer Web Pa...
Shared Documents
Site Users 
Tasks
Team Discussion
User Tasks
XML Web Part
```

Where should I start to simply achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think we have a web part like that but an alternative you can apply is to call SharePoint Web Service via jQuery in Content Editor Web Part to achieve the same.

Another similar approach [here](http://michael.wilcox.net/2007/10/12/show-all-subsites-in-a-webpart/).